# All the folders and files I create with java are being created with a lock image in Ubuntu 18

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have a program that during it's normal execution creates some folders and files. This worked great on my machine, both windows 10 and ubuntu 18. But now I'm trying it in other ubuntu 18 and all the folders and files are created with a lock, which makes my program work incorrectly.

I'm guessing is has something to do with permissions, I tried running `sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME` but still have the same problem.

I'm the admin. I have this problem when I run `sudo ./run.sh`. If I run `sh run.sh` I don't have this problem.

Comment: What are the *actual* uid, gid, and mode of the files? What user is your Java program running as? Does that user match the user under which you are running your file manager that sees the locks?

Comment: This reads *slightly* more like a Linux problem than a programming problem.  Since the application is invariant (you don't make changes between the different OSes), this feels like an issue with permissions in the folder you're writing to - the application might have the right permissions, but *you* probably don't.

Comment: What permission your folders/files are using? You program run in your local machine?